# How do i test for http status code 500 in sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have the following code in my main class in nodejs.

I am doing unit testing using sinon.

How do I test for this portion of the code 
`res.status(error.status || 500);`

I am able to test the error.status portion by call an invalid url which leads to the error handling above, 404, but how do i get to the `500` flow?

**main.js:**

```
...
//importing route
var routes = require('./api/rest/webservRest'); 

//register the route
routes(app); 

//reached here throw error 404, means no routes to handle inc. request
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;

    next(error);
});

// catch errors
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {

    log.error("ERROR - " + req.url + " - " + error.message);

    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    }); 
});

//start application
module.exports = app.listen(port, () => {
    log.info('Module - RESTful API server started on: ' + port);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`500` will be caught if `error.status` return falsy value such as `false` or `undefined`.

So perhaps you can stubing the `error` using Sinon as below:

```
const error = {
  status: false,
  message: 'something'
}
```

or

```
const error = {
  message: 'something'
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I still don't get it. Does it mean that i need to stub `app.use((error, req, res, next)`?